# Get specific part of string between specific characters

Tags: javascript

I have my string variable `source.Changes`, which stores different strings. For example, it can store values like these:

```
[["DriveTypeId",1,2]]
[["LocationId",null,3]
```

Basically I would like to get the part between the`" "` characters. So from `[["DriveTypeId",1,2]]` I would get `DriveTypeId`.

So far I have tried codes like this `source.Changes.split("")[0]` but with no luck.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this looks like either json or actual javascript arrays. manually parsing json is a bad idea. try `JSON.parse('[["DriveTypeId",1,2]]')[0][0]`

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. - Whether it's intentionally JSON or not, both examples are valid JSON, so that would be a useful answer to post (as a answer) with the caveat that you only know about the two values given and are extrapolating.

Comment: nina beat me to it.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce.
Alright, that works fine, thank you a lot.

Comment: @AdamSulc - if that's what you used please remember to mark nina's answer with the check mark.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Yeah, I am aware of that, just need to wait few minutes untill SO allows me to :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the [JSON](https://json.org/) compliant string and get the value.

```js
var string = '[["DriveTypeId",1,2]]',
    parsed = JSON.parse(string),
    value = parsed[0][0];

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with a capture group:

```js
const str = '[["DriveTypeId",1,2]]';
const match = /"([^"]+)/.exec(str);
if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Or if you can target environments with look-behind, you don't need a capture group:

```js
const str = '[["DriveTypeId",1,2]]';
const match = /(?<=")[^"]+/.exec(str);
if (match) {
    console.log(match[0]);
}
```

---

Note that both of those assume there are no escaped `"` within the string. **If** this is valid JSON as [I wrestled a bear once observes it might be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806306/get-specific-part-of-string-between-specific-characters/57806385#comment102044269_57806306), use `JSON.parse` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are correct and indeed the stored value is actually a string, you can just do

`source.Changes.split('"')[1]`

example:

`'[["DriveTypeId",1,2]]'.split('"')[1]`
returns "DriveTypeId"